# hide() is working properly, but not fadeOut()?

Tags: jquery, video, hide, slideshow, show

I have a jquery slideshow with hold frames and videos. When the hold frame is clicked, I want it to fade out and the video to fade in and play.

It works with show() and hide(), but when I change it to fadeIn() and fadeOut() the whole thing breaks.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
          $('.holdFrame1').click(function(){  
            $(".holdFrame1").delay(500).hide();         
            $(".hiddenVideo1").show(
            function(){          
               $f(players[0]).api('play');                                                                                                                     
});
```

This is what I would like to accomplish

```
          $('.holdFrame1').click(function(){  
            $(".holdFrame1").delay(500).fadeOut('slow');         
            $(".hiddenVideo1").show(
             function(){          
               $f(players[0]).api('play');                                                                                                                     
       });
      });
```

But that causes the image not to fadeOut, but rather stay in place while the hidden video appears below it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole thing breaks"? What actually happens? It doesn't do something, or it does something wrong?

Comment: Can I see a example for your fadeIn and fadeOut code?

Comment: If I put any kind of parameters in the hide() ('slow'), the video doesn't hide and the hidden one appears right below it.

Comment: The fact that none of the answers given solves your problem implies that your problem doesn't lie here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) (and [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)) correctly with callbacks. So the method signature you're looking for is:

```
.fadeOut( [duration] [, callback] )
```

I have to predict what your markup looks like, but in general this isn't too difficult. Using:

```
.videoContainer {
    background: grey;
    height: 400px;
    width: 560px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.holdFrame,
.hiddenVideo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.holdFrame {
    background: green;
}
.hiddenVideo {
    background: yellow;
    display: none;
}

<div class="videoContainer">
    <div class="holdFrame">Click to play video.</div>
    <div class="hiddenVideo">Video will be here.</div>
</div>
```

You can:

```
$(".holdFrame").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.fadeOut(500, function(){
        $this.siblings('.hiddenVideo').fadeIn(500, function (){
            $f(players[0]).api('play');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeRxP/

The nice thing about this (in which I'm fairly certain I've modified your markup and CSS without knowing it), you can have more than one video player on the same page and they won't conflict:

http://jsfiddle.net/yeRxP/2/

Since I'm not familiar with your video player, you'll have to modify it to play the correct video on the `.fadeIn()` callback.

Comment: can you explain to me what the .siblings is doing in this function?

Comment: I put the `<div class="holdFrame">Click to play video.</div>` and `<div class="hiddenVideo">Video will be here.</div>` together, so I use `.siblings()` to select which element to show. If you have more than one `hiddenVideo` on the page, you can't select `.hiddenVideo` as you have in your code without showing every one. It's just a way of encapsulating and localizing the action.

Comment: Each hidden video has a unique ID. .hiddenVideo1, .hiddenVideo2, etc. That way I can fadeOut depending on which hold frame is clicked.

Comment: I don't under stand why something like  `$('.holdFrame1').click(function(){   
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {          
          $(".hiddenVideo1").show();
          $f(players[0]).api('play');
       });
});` doesn't work, but the standard hide() does.

Comment: Those aren't `id`s, those are class names. You're not using `class` and `id` attributes correctly. If you select with `.hiddenVideo1`, that's a class, and classes are by nature groups. You can use `id="hiddenVideo1"` and `#hiddenVideo1` if you want, but as I demonstrate in the code (after removing the `1, 2, 3` etc.), you don't really need to if you handle the code and the class structure correctly.

Comment: And at least here: http://jsfiddle.net/yeRxP/3/ What you have in the above comment works with a single example (I've removed the `1` as a demonstration). You're using classes to denote individual elements (which is what `id`s are for), so you've got to attach individual handlers for each element with your class name-based `id`s, or treat them as groups and localize the code as I demonstrated.

Comment: See: *[The id attribute assigns a unique identifier to an element... The class attribute, on the other hand, assigns one or more class names to an element; the element may be said to belong to these classes.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)*

Comment: Oh ok, that's right. I didn't even think about that. Let's say i DO want to use unique IDs. I still can't get it to fade out properly. If i hide it, the holdFrame goes away, but if i change it to fade out, it stays in place! so frustrating!

Comment: Without seeing the actual code/markup you're using, it's hard to say.

Comment: Here's the same code from your comment, with the `.delay(500)` incorporated: http://jsfiddle.net/yeRxP/8/ There has to be something else that's not been caught yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace show() with fadeIn() and use a call back you need to use a speed associated with the fadeIn():

```
$('.holdFrame1').click(function(){   
    $(".holdFrame1").fadeOut('slow');          
    $(".hiddenVideo1").fadeIn('slow', function(){
        $f(players[0]).api('play');
    });
});
```

For more information: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: I tried this and the fadeIn works, but the top initial image won't go away unless i change it to hide(). I would like it to fadeOut().

Comment: Try removing the delay on your fadeOut?

Comment: I removed the delay but it still won't fade out. Hiding it still works though.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pA58v/

```
<button class="holdFrame1">test</button>

<video class="hiddenVideo1" style="border:1px solid #000"></video>​


$(document).ready(function() {

$(".hiddenVideo1").hide();  

$('.holdFrame1').click(function(){  
        $(".holdFrame1").delay(500).hide();         
        $(".hiddenVideo1").show();       
         $f(players[0]).api('play');              
      });


});
```